# SharePoint hidden list searching error

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, list-view-threshold, hidden

While searching hidden users list in SharePoint using username, the data can't be displayed because threshold limit error is showing.

How can we rectify this error?

Can this be solved if we delete the users from the list. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: If you delete the users from the list they will no longer have SharePoint access.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SPO or SP on-prem?

If you're using SP on-prem, it is possible to increase list view threshold.

Go to Central Admin>Click **Manage Web Applications** under Application Management>Select the web application for which you’re adjusting the list view threshold>Select **General Settings** then **Resource Throttling**:
[image]

In addition, you can also check this official document on how to manage list/library:

[The number of items in this list exceeds the list view threshold" when you view lists in Office 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/items-exceeds-list-view-threshold)

Reference:
[Sharepoint List View Threshold](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/191627/sharepoint-list-view-threshold.html)